# About codigniter owl carousel class

Tags: php

is codeigniter supports owl.carousel class I am to able to see my slider if I run a run a program if I use codeigniter but I am if I not use codeigniter sliders work

Answer (score 0):

Yes, owl-carousel works in Codeigniter. Inspect elements and check if you receive errors. This is how I call my owl-carousel.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/inc/owl-carousel/css/owl.carousel.css') ?>">
```